# Conversion of integer array to a string in Android/Java

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have an array:

```
int A = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

I would like to display it on phone screen as a single string 123456 (or 1 2 3 4 5 6) (i.e. with a space between each number. Could you please help to let me know how to do it?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java

Comment: just google it, if you cannot find then place the question here dude.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut:

```
String line = "";
for(int temp : A) {
    line = line + (""+temp);
}
System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of loop and StringBuilder:

> Note, using StringBuilder is greatly recommended when dealing with String and String concatenation in a loop process. Read this for reference: [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

```
int[] A = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < A.length; ctr++){
    sb.append(A[ctr]);

    //print separator only when there are items after this one.
    if(ctr < A.length -1){
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If only printing is the issue, then why not do it in a simple way,

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    System.out.print(A[i]);//not println
}
System.out.println();//just add an extra line.
```

Another can be, `Arrays.toString(A)//verify this.`